# Angular 4 Can't bind to <property> since it isn't a known property of <component>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create my own directive in Angular 4. But, I got this error when bind the property of class into component template.

Console error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
'data' since it isn't a known property of 'tree'. ("<tree [ERROR
->][data]="data"></tree>"):
```

My tree-view-component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tree-view',
    template: '<tree [data]="data"></tree>'
})
export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() data: any[];

    constructor() {
        this.data = [
        {
            label: 'a1',
            subs: [
                {
                    label: 'a11',
                    subs: [
                        {
                            label: 'a111',
                            subs: [
                                {
                                    label: 'a1111'
                                },
                                {
                                    label: 'a1112'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'a112'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'a12',
                }
            ]
         }
     ];
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Here is my complete script file: https://pastebin.com/hDyX2Kjj

Is there anyone know about this? TiA

Comment: You don't need to mark inputs twice, either ` inputs: ['data'],` or `@Input()` if you have both, one is redundant. Did you add `Node` to `declarations of `@NgModule()`?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5 provides a ready to use Angular2 template - just press the "new" button and "Angular".

Comment: It was solved with added TreeNodeComponent, TreeComponent, adn TreeViewComponent to declarations array in @NgModule().

Is there another way to include TreeViewComponent only in @NgModule() without TreeNodeComponent and TreeComponent? Because I already included its in TreeViewComponent.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean with "Because I already included its in TreeViewComponent." Do you mean `TreeViewModule`?

Comment: I did `import { TreeNodeComponent } from './tree-view.node.component';` in TreeComponent and `import { TreeComponent } from './tree.component';` in TreeViewComponent. Why should I include them again in app.module?

Doesn't it enough with just including TreeViewComponent in declarations?

Comment: TypeScript imports and declarations are two entirely different and unrelated concepts. Every component, directive, pipe, needs to be registered in `@NgModule({ declaration: []})`. Either in `AppModule` or a module added to `imports: []` of `AppModule` (direct or transitive).

Comment: Can it be the same if I create a TreeModule, which means it will be separated with AppModule, and add TreeNodeComponent, TreeComponent, and TreeViewComponent into TreeModule declarations, and then import TreeModule to AppModule, So, I don't need add them into AppModule declarations again?

Comment: Exactly. This is called a feature module and will work fine. This makes it easier to reuse the tree in other modules. You need to import the module that contains directives you use into every module where you use them and directives (and components and pipes) can only be in `declarations: []` of exactly one module.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you for your great explanation :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Every component, directive, and pipe needs to be registered in `@NgModule()`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TreeViewComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For more details see

- https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule
- https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules
- https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-api

Comment: How about this

`tree.module.ts`:
'
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TreeNodeComponent,
    TreeComponent,
    TreeViewComponent
  ]
...
...
'

and in `app.module.ts`:
`
imports: [
     ...
     TreeModule
     ...
]
`

Can it?

Comment: Yup, as mentioned below your question, that's usually the right way, but usually more difficult to understand for people not yet familiar with `@NgModule()`. But it seems you got it already ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Can you please update the link? Current link is broken.

Comment: @BhavikShah Thanks for the hint! Updated.

Answer (score 6):

I've the same error, when run test for ParentComponent. Inside was ChildComponent component with @Input property: string;.
Both components were also declared inside app.module.ts.

I've fixed this like that (parent component test file):

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent]// added child component declaration here
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 2):

As *The Aelfinn* pointed out if you are using your Component across Modules you need to export it. **BUT** you should not import, export and declare it in the Module you want to use it, since its not part of this Module !!! 
So suppose you have a **TreeViewStuffModule** which declares the **TreeViewComponent** and a **DoSomethingWithTreeViewModule** where the TreeViewComponent is used in, your declarations would be as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TreeViewComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    TreeViewComponent
  ]
})
export class TreeViewStuffModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TreeViewStuffModule
  ]
})
export class DoSomethingWithTreeViewModule
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **TreeViewComponent** in another module, you will need to **import** the component into the `@NgModule` as follows:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [TreeViewComponent],
    // This says that all components in this module can import TreeViewComponent
    exports: [ThisModulesComponents],
    declarations: [ThisModulesComponents]
})
export class ModuleDependentOnTreeViewComponent
```

Comment: You should not import export and declare the Component in some other Module it is not part of