# Angular module from npm missing @NgModule declaration

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

A module from NPM is missing @NgModule, @Directive declarations, though it is in the source code on Github. This is preventing me from importing a directive to databind from an HTML attribute.

---

I'm trying to use the angular-gtag package to log custom dimensions to Google Analytics using the [params] attribute as defined in the readme here: https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-gtag

```
<div gtagEvent trackOn="click" action="myAction" [params]="{ myDimension: myDimensionValue}"></div>
```

Where myDimensionValue is a variable of the containing component.

This causes an error:

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'params' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Reading up on this error (such as here: [Angular 4 Can't bind to <property> since it isn't a known property of <component>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131227/angular-4-cant-bind-to-property-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-component) or here: [Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522877/cant-bind-to-x-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-y)) leads to the suggestion that I need to add the GtagEventDirective class to the declarations in app.module.ts.

However, doing that leads to the error

```
Unexpected module 'GtagModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation
```

Looking in the source of the package in node_modules, any @Component or @Directive annotations are absent. Strangely enough, they are present in the module's source code on Github: https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-gtag/blob/master/lib/src/gtag-event.directive.ts and https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-gtag/blob/master/lib/src/gtag.module.ts

So what can I do here? Editing the code in node_modules doesn't seem like the best idea and changes here may not even be picked up as there are already transpiled files in the package.

I tried reinstalling the package. I'm certain I have the latest version (1.0.3) and the source in Github also lists that version as the latest.

Of course I could create an issue in the Github repo, but the source code there is correct. Any change I could ask for is already in there. My problem seems to be somewhere between NPM and my machine.

Comment: can you show how you imported the `GtagModule` in your `AppModule`?

Comment: As per the instructions in the readme, I've added it as follows:
`import { GtagModule} from 'angular-gtag';`

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
    GtagModule.forRoot({ trackingId: 'UA-something', trackPageviews: true })
    ...
  ],
  ...
})

Comment: the package you download from npm will not have the source code and/or a js file with `@Directive`. This is only used in typescript, and the npm module probably just ships the compiled es5 code

Comment: npm module is fine. I got it to work. We need to see how you are doing things to find your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application has a custom RouterModule. I had to import the GtagModule there and then it worked.

```
import { GtagModule } from 'angular-gtag';

@NgModule({
  imports: [GtagModule]
})
export class CustomRoutingModule
```

In the error message, the source is given as ng://CustomRouterModule/MyComponent.html which indicates there is a custom router that's causing the problem.

Comment: You are probably using it in a sub-module. because it works with a routing module https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2ezcx If so, this is the same concept of why we use a SharedModule and importing in RoutingModule is not something I would recommend

Answer (score 1):

The library on npm is not missing anything. But since we cant see your code. I'm going to post what I did.

package.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "angular-gtag":"1.0.3",
    "core-js": "2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
...
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GTM-5FJXX6">
    </script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'GTM-5FJXX6', { 'send_page_view': false });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>loading</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { GtagModule } from 'angular-gtag';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
  imports:
    [
      GtagModule.forRoot({ trackingId: 'GTM-5FJXX6', trackPageviews: true }),

      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(
        [
          { path: "", component: HelloComponent }
        ]
      ),

    ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Gtag } from 'angular-gtag';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
   constructor(gtag: Gtag) {}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div gtagEvent
     trackOn="dragstart"
     action="product_dragged"
     category="ecommerce"
     [params]="{ event_label: 'Something cool just happened' }">

   Some Product...

</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2ezcx) If you still don't find where. replicate your issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

The only way I can replicate your error is by removing gtagEvent from the div

Answer (score 0):

If the source is correct but files are missing in the release, you can link directly your depedendency to github.

try :

```
npm install --save https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-gtag#master
```